# Mexican Visa required for short tourist visa for Sri Lankan National?

Tags: mexico, sri-lankan-citizens, fmm-tourist-card

For a Sri Lankan national, is a mexican visa required or just the FMM only? This will be for a short tourist stay for about 30 days and we will travel by plane. I searched online and found confusing answers where only the FMM was required.

Answer (score 12):

You may find the [official rules for tourist visa exemption](https://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/toronto/index.php/en/servicesforeigners/doclegalization/52-conservices/225-visitors-who-do-not-require-a-visa-with-a-stay-up-to-180-days) on Mexico's web sites:

> **Citizens from the following countries who wish to visit Mexico as tourists, in transit, for business, technical activities, as journalist or for studies, for a period not exceeding 180 days, and who will not receive any remuneration at all in Mexican territory, *do not require a visa:***
>
> Andorra, Argentina, Australia, Austria, Bahamas Barbados, Belgium, Belize, Brazil, Bulgaria, Canada, Chile, Colombia, Cook Islands, Costa Rica, Croatia, Cyprus, Czech Republic, Denmark, Ecuador, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hong Kong, Hungary, Iceland, Ireland, Israel, Italy, Jamaica, Japan, Latvia, Lichtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Macau, Malaysia, Malta, Marshall Islands, Micronesia, Monaco, Netherlands, New Zealand, Niue, Norway, Palau, Panama, Paraguay, Peru, Poland, Portugal, Romania, San Marino, Singapore, Slovakia, Slovenia, South Korea, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, Trinidad and Tobago, United Arab Emirates, United Kingdom, United States of America, Uruguay, Venezuela.
>
> *All foreign visitors, regardless of their nationality, traveling to Mexico for tourism, business or in transit to another destination, **are exempt from presenting a Mexican visa** as long as they have a valid visa issued by any the following countries: Canada, Japan, the United States of America, the United Kingdom or any of the countries comprising the Schengen Area.*
>
> In addition, foreign visitors who, regardless of their nationality, have a valid permanent resident card from Canada, Chile, Colombia, Japan, Peru, the United States of America, the United Kingdom or any of the countries comprising the Schengen Area, do not require a Mexican visa.

You will see that Sri Lanka is not listed, so unless you qualify for one of the other exemptions, you will require a visa.

Comment: Weird, I called Turkish Airlines (US number) and gave them the details and they said their system shows I don't need any visa to board the plane to Cancun Mexico from Istanbul. They said to double check with the Mexican embassy so I'm trying to do that...so far unable as their "Visa" department isn't picking up in the US.

Comment: @zwdev2 I just quoted chapter and verse from the Mexican embassy! Whoever at Turkish Airlines is mistaken, and that will be a very expensive mistake _for you_. They will hold you responsible if Mexico refuses you entry because you did not have a visa.